# Simulate click on marker with KML with Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, kml

I'm using a kml file to create markers on the map.

I need to simulate a click on a marker to open the info window by clicking an external elements (i.s. a div) knowing latitutude and longitude cords.

What i can do?

Answer (score 0):

<s>here are at least two options:</s>

One option:

- Render your KML using a third-party KML parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) which render the KML as native Google Maps API v3 objects, keep references to them and use those to trigger a click event on the object (works for markers, polygons and polylines), loses the benefit of KmlLayer tile based rendering.

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=VoterDistricts_address.xml)

**no longer available, FusionTables was retired December 3, 2019**
- Import your KML into FusionTables, then query the table for the data to create the InfoWindow when desired (**Note: This is no longer useful, Fusion Tables was shut down on December 3, 2019**)

[example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

Comment: Thanks this was the solutions! :D